# Can I play video games online with men?

Tags: halal-haram

To be honest.. I started playing fortnite with a few friends online(they are boys). We all are JUST FRIENDS and no haram intentions are involved alhamdulillah. We are a group of four and all of us play together, I never play with any one of them alone. Is that also haram?

Comment: If you are a boy , then it's not a problem. If you are a girl, it shall be permissible as far no wrong things are done or intended( like talking to attract one other , etc, etc)

Comment: @An_Elephant Wrong...

Comment: **Talking with people of the opposing gender should be avoided, unless absolutely necessary.** This is based on multiple verses from the Quran and hadith which amply that conversing with someone of the opposite gender, whether in a group or not, is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is no haram activities (forbidden things according to Islam), there is no wrong in playing with other people. One thing to make sure is even though there is no haram activities now, you should be sure you will not indulge in haram activities due to this friendship.  For whatever reason, you think it is not allowed, please update the question with your reason so we can know why you think it is not allowed. I will update my answer, when you update the question.

Answer (score -4):

Playing video games in and of itself is impermissible, so you should refrain from that.

And Allah knows best.